# searchrawtransactions in bitcoin-cli returning "Method not found" error

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, client, nodes, bitcoin-cli

some days ago I installed bitcoin core patched with the addrindex option ( [btcdrak version](https://github.com/btcdrak/bitcoin/tree/addrindex-0.12) ), after indexing the entire blockchain for 5 days, I tried to use the **searchrawtransactions** parameter on bitcoin-cli in order to query some addresses, but it is returning the following error:

```
error code: -32601
error message:
Method not found
```

In github I saw the following statement:

> First run will require a full reindex of the blockchain. After that, the searchrawtransactions will be available.

But it's not working for me. Anyone has experience with this or with any other bitcoin core patched version?

Comment: To me it sounds like you're not actually running the addrindex patched branch.

Answer (score 2):

There is no cli API as `searchrawtransaction` in the core bitcoin client. I guess what you are talking about is `getrawtransaction`. [This](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list) would be place where you would find all the API's aggregated in one page and you can search for the API you are concerned with.

Comment: No, I'm talking about searchrawtransactions available in this BTC core version: https://github.com/btcdrak/bitcoin/tree/addrindex-0.12

Comment: @Nucklear Oh, I am sorry. Did you check the issues? https://github.com/btcdrak/bitcoin/issues/12

Comment: Yes I already checked but I did not get anything usefull